# return View("название View") не удалось найти ресурс

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Сабж.
Мой код

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Request.UserLanguages.Count() != 0 & Request.UserLanguages.Contains("ru-RU"))
            return View("Ru");

        return View();
    }
```

Представление Ru существует, в той же папке, что и Index

Comment: а если прописать полный путь? return View("~/Views/___/ru.cshtml");

Comment: представление с указанным именем ищется в следующих местах: **Views/Controller/ИмяПредставления** или **Views/Shared/ИмяПредставления**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Путь к этому представлению будет выглядеть как /{controller}/{action}, Т.е. в вашем случае localhost:port/controller/**Index**, и только тогда будет производится поиск представления "Ru.cshtml".

Маршрут обращается к методу действия, а не к файлу.

Вы можете добавить свой маршрут в RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "MyPath",
    url: "{controller}/RU",
    defaults: new { controller = "Ваш_контроллер", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: можно указать имя конкретного представления но оно должно быть доступно по одному из путей **Views/Controller/ИмяПредставления** или **Views/Shared/ИмяПредставления**